# Using delay for a function multiple times in java

Tags: java, delayed-execution

I'm trying to create a Pacman game. The ghosts have such a restriction at the beginning of each round and each time they return to their home (after eating Pacman or being eaten by it), that have to stay there for a certain period of time. I've tried some methods such as Timer and TimerTask and ScheduledExecutorServicea. But all to no avail!
My problem is the delay works only the first time -with both methods- and even though I re-instantiate the schedulers each time it doesn't work. I'm looking for a way to make it delay each time after the previously mentioned conditions.

Thanks for your help and attention in advance.

is where I define the runnables that each move a ghost.

```
private Runnable ghost1Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Point2D[] ghost1Coordinates = moveThisGhost(ghost1Location, ghost1Velocity);
        ghost1Location = ghost1Coordinates[0];
        ghost1Velocity = ghost1Coordinates[1];
        ghost1HasStopped = false;
        canGhost1EatOrBeEaten = true;
    }
};
private Runnable ghost2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Point2D[] ghost2Coordinates = moveThisGhost(ghost2Location, ghost2Velocity);
        ghost2Location = ghost2Coordinates[0];
        ghost2Velocity = ghost2Coordinates[1];
        ghost2HasStopped = false;
        canGhost2EatOrBeEaten = true;
    }
};

private Runnable ghost3Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Point2D[] ghost3Coordinates = moveThisGhost(ghost3Location, ghost3Velocity);
        ghost3Location = ghost3Coordinates[0];
        ghost3Velocity = ghost3Coordinates[1];
        ghost3HasStopped = false;
        canGhost3EatOrBeEaten = true;
    }
};

private Runnable ghost4Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Point2D[] ghost4Coordinates = moveThisGhost(ghost4Location, ghost4Velocity);
        ghost4Location = ghost4Coordinates[0];
        ghost4Velocity = ghost4Coordinates[1];
        ghost4HasStopped = false;
        canGhost4EatOrBeEaten = true;
    }
};
```

and here I run them in a function

```
    public void moveGhosts() {
    if (ghost1HasStopped) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ghost1Scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ghost1Scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ghost1Runnable, 5 ,5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    else
        ghost1Runnable.run();
    if (ghost2HasStopped) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ghost2Scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ghost2Scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ghost2Runnable, 5 ,5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    else
        ghost2Runnable.run();
    if (ghost3HasStopped) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ghost3Scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ghost3Scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ghost3Runnable, 5 ,5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    else
        ghost3Runnable.run();
    if (ghost4HasStopped) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ghost4Scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ghost4Scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ghost4Runnable, 5 ,5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    else
        ghost4Runnable.run();
}
```

and here i reset the conditions for delay:

```
public void resetAllGhostsDelay() {
    canGhost1EatOrBeEaten = false;
    canGhost2EatOrBeEaten = false;
    canGhost3EatOrBeEaten = false;
    canGhost4EatOrBeEaten = false;
    ghost1HasStopped = true;
    ghost2HasStopped = true;
    ghost3HasStopped = true;
    ghost4HasStopped = true;
}
```

and i aslo do this eah time a single ghost is eaten:

```
    public void returnThisGhostToInitialLocation(Cell ghost) {
    if (ghost == Cell.GHOST_1_HOME) {
        ghost1Location = new Point2D(ghost1InitialLocation.getX(), ghost1InitialLocation.getY());
        ghost1HasStopped = true;
    }
    else if (ghost == Cell.GHOST_2_HOME) {
        ghost2Location = new Point2D(ghost2InitialLocation.getX(), ghost2InitialLocation.getY());
        ghost2HasStopped = true;
    }
    else if (ghost == Cell.GHOST_3_HOME) {
        ghost3Location = new Point2D(ghost3InitialLocation.getX(), ghost3InitialLocation.getY());
        ghost3HasStopped = true;
    }
    else if (ghost == Cell.GHOST_4_HOME) {
        ghost4Location = new Point2D(ghost4InitialLocation.getX(), ghost4InitialLocation.getY());
        ghost4HasStopped = true;
    }
}
```

I've done something similar using TimerTask and Timer but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you please provide some code reproducing the problem ?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mre] that we can run and test in our IDE.